# returning requested data in C to ajax(jquery) CGI

Tags: javascript, jquery, c, ajax, cgi

Im returning specific data in to my jquery using C, how will i put the data in C?
str

```
 function Run() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
     var obj = {"method":"pref-get","arguments":{"infos":["sys_info"]}};
        alert("Post Json:" + JSON.stringify(obj));
         $.ajax({
             url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/try.cgi",
              type: 'POST', 
              data: JSON.stringify(obj),
              dataType: 'text',
              success: function(response){
              alert(response);
                        }
       });
    }
    Run();
```

the Value_in_C must have the data in the CGI.
Heres the code for C:

```
if(!end && !strcmp(method, "GET"))
    printf(("%s"), str);
    response = (("%s"), str);   
    fclose(fd);
```

How can I pass or return the value of str to the alert function?
Or should i add function in C to response in POST/GET method?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is an basic ajax problem, isn't it?

You have: client > call "try.cgi" in server > response data ("Value_in_C") to client > display it.

Then it should be:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/try.cgi",
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(obj),
  dataType: 'text', // since your response is a string
  success: function(responseData){
      alert(responseData); // responseData should be "Value_in_C"
  }
});
```

Updated: dataType: 'json' will parse response to json, so "Value_in_C" became null

Comment: Do your script "try.cgi" response anything? Did you simply do [print "Value_in_C"]

Comment: Yup I simply use [printf]. Question: how will i respond to POST method?

Comment: But when I go directly to 'try.cgi' it responses well. But when I use the client, it displays 'null'. I will post my code for C for further reference.

Comment: Change ajax type to [type: 'GET'], what its response?

Comment: By using json data, you may get some troubles with parser, so try text first, then change to json after that. You should check what you get from the server first. In another hand, are you sure that your [obj] is not null?

Comment: Edited: posted the function for the JSON. Btw by replacing the data type by 'text' it works!